# How do I transfer my photos from my cloud to my Mac?

Tags: icloud, photos, library

I don't want my photos from my Mac going into my cloud. I only want to put my photos from my cloud onto my iMac....how do I do this?

I tried a few things and the end result was  7,000 pictures that were in my photos app on the computer starting to fill up my cloud.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Can you please edit your question (there's an _edit_ link below it) to include what you've already tried? Saying _I tried a few things _ doesn't really help us to help you. Also, can you clarify what your current settings are in terms of iCloud and your Photos app?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to download them from iCloud using the web interface and then load them onto your Mac. There's no option in iCloud Photo Library to go one way only.